# Laravel Resource controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How do I tell my API to display a particular result based on another column?

e.g. `localhost:8000/api/gadgets/{{id}}`

Normally it returns the particular information of the specific gadget with that `ID` and `localhost:8000/api/gadgets/{{imei_code}}` does not return any value or an error whereas `imei_code` is a column that I needed to pass as a GET request...

I'm using the normal resource controller

```
public function show(Gadgets $gadget)
{
    $response = ['data' => new GadgetResource($gadget), 'message' => 'specific gadget'];

    return response($response, 200);  
}
```

Also I need help on how I can create like a search function in the  controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the model key by scoping - check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-scoping-resource-routes)

```
Route::resource('gadgets', GadgetController::class)->scoped([
    'gadget' => 'imei_code'
]);
```

Than, when Laravel try to bind Gadget model in Controller - model will will be searched by key `imei_code`.

This code equvalent of

`Route::get('/gadget/{gadget:imei_code}');`

Answer (score 1):

You can`t do two similar URLs. I think your route for URL

> localhost:8000/api/gadgets/{{imei_code}}

isn`t work. Also the order of the routes is important and route that defined firstly will be have higer priority then route that defined secondly.
Because your routes /api/gadgets/{{id}} and /api/gadgets/{{imei_code}} is similar in this case only the one described earlier will be processed.

You can define another router and handler, for example:

> localhost:8000/api/gadgets

That will return a list of gadgets by default and you can add filters for imei_code. For example:

> localhost:8000/api/gadgets?imei_code=123

And your handler for the new route may be writed something like that:

```
public function showList(Request $request): GadgetResource
{
    if ($imeiCode = $request->query('imei_code')) {
        $list = Gadget::query()->where('imei_code', $imeiCode)->get();
    } else {
        $list = Gadget::query()->take(10)->get();
    }

    return GadgetResource::collection($list);
}
```

---

Or like alternative solution you can create diferent route for searching of gadgets exactly by imei_code to get rid of any route conflicts

> localhost:8000/api/gadgets/by_imei/123

```
public function findByImei(Request $request): GadgetResource
{
    $imeiCode = $request->route('imei_code');
    $item = Gadget::query()->where('imei_code', $imeiCode)->first();

    return new GadgetResource($item);
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try to change response

```
public function show(Gadgets $gadget)
{
    $response = ['data' => new GadgetResource($gadget), 'message' => 'specific gadget'];
    return response()->json($response);  
}
```